# reduce styled-component className length in next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

When using `styled-components` in **Next** with **React**, it can become challenging to ensure that the styled components render correctly. To address this issue, **Next** supplies the `compiler.styledComponents` flag
in `next.config.js` as follows:

```
compiler: {
    styledComponents: true
}
```

However, when this flag is enabled, it leads to the class names becoming unreadable as they increase in size *exponentially*.

The following images illustrate the difference in class names between when `compiler.styledComponents` is disabled and when it is enabled.

When `compiler.styledComponents` *is not* set:

[image: before]

When `compiler.styledComponents` *is* set:

[image: after]

Is there a way to reduce the class name sizes to just their regular `sc-XXXXXX` names?

I should note that we're *not* using the latest version of **Next**, but instead `next@12.3.4`

Comment: have you experimented with displayName and fileName options in next.config.js? See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#styled-components

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Disable `displayName` in `babel-plugin-styled-components`

Thanks to @vlad-vladov for pointing out the docs for this.

In [the Next.js 12 and 13 docs for the Next.js compiler](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#styled-components), it is stated that Next.js is using a port of `babel-plugin-styled-components` and that the `displayName` option is enabled by default in development and disabled in production. [The documentation for `babel-plugin-styled-components`](https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging) states the following about the `displayName` option:

> This option enhances the attached CSS class name on each component with richer output to help identify your components in the DOM without React DevTools. In your page source you'll see: `<button class="Button-asdf123 asdf123" />` instead of just `<button class="asdf123" />`.

To disable `displayName`, just put `false`:

```js
module.exports = {
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: { displayName: false }
  }
}
```

And to further explain why your class names were so long, the `fileName` option (enabled by default) adds the name of the current file to the beginning of the `displayName` when it's enabled.

Comment: Perfect – thank you! Although, I opted to keep the `displayName` property enabled and just disabled `fileName`. :-)